# Pass Curl object to next page

Tags: php, curl

I am using curl request

My Code

```
$url = "http://www.somesite.com/members/";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "myusername:mypassword");
$output = curl_exec($ch);
```

I want to pass the curl object "$ch" to next page. 
I have tried using session and cookies. But nothing happened.

How i will achieve this ? Please help me out

Answer (score 3):

You cannot store resources in the session: they are in-memory data structures that have no fixation logic. Per [the documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php):

> Some types of data can not be serialized thus stored in sessions. It includes resource variables or objects with circular references (i.e. objects which passes a reference to itself to another object).

You can either:

1. pass the URL to the next page and perform the download again, or
2. pass the output to the next page and process it.